# GLUT What are overlays good for?

Tags: opengl, window, glut

> When overlay hardware is available, GLUT provides a set of routine for establishing, using, and removing an overlay for GLUT windows. When an overlay is established, a separate OpenGL context is also established. A window's overlay OpenGL state is kept distinct from the normal planes OpenGL state. [[1]](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node29.html#SECTION00060000000000000000)

#### What are overlays

I don't quite understand their potential even with a description from other sources. Would you describe what they are and what they are used for?

What does `overlay hardware` mean? How could something like *"OpenGL context thingy"* be hardware dependent assuming that the OpenGL context of the normal plane works.

#### Overlays vs Subwindows

I quite understand that overlays are used to separate the OpenGL context. So are they similar to subwindows? (as they both have separate context) Where is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL overlays are a legacy feature that was supported by hardly any implementation. Most notably you could use them on old SGI machines made in the previous millenium, and then some graphics cards made by 3Dlabs before they went defunct.

Essentially they enabled to render several "layers" of content, which would be composited upon scanout. Their use was in enabling a way to draw user interface elements on top of renderings, that could be changed without having to re-render the whole thing.

These days you're far better off using off-screen rendering into framebuffer objects and composition to achieve the same result, without going through all the trouble that overlays were.

My recommendation: Try to forget, that you've ever read about this feature and ignore it in the future. It has not been relevant for over 20 years.